# Pulling from database and updating database at the same time

Tags: python, sql, multithreading, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is it possible to run a python flask app that pulls from a sql database, while also running a python script that updates the sql database every few seconds?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, databases are designed to handle this type of concurrent access. If the database is in the middle of an update, it will wait until the update is complete before handling the Flask app's query, and it will complete the query before starting the next incoming update.

Comment: What happens if the database is constantly being updated without breaks?

Comment: The requests are queued; a newly arrived update doesn't take precedence over a query that is waiting. Also, my answer is a little simplistic. A request doesn't necessarily lock the entire database. If the database can determine that two requests are completely independent, they can be processed in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for this info!